# Setting form control's value from within template

Tags: angular

I have a template which displays shipping methods as Radio buttons like
Shipping methods are loaded over a Service.

I want to set the FormControl `shipping_method`'s value to the id of first option
how may I do this?

```html
<div class="form-row" *ngIf="shippingMethods$ | async; let shippingMethods; ">
  <div class="form-group radio" *ngIf="shippingMethods.length > 0">
    <h2>Versandart:</h2>
    <label *ngFor="let shippingMethod of shippingMethods; let idx = index" for="method-{{ shippingMethod.id }}">
      <input formControlName="shipping_method" type="radio" value="{{ shippingMethod.id }}"
        id="method-{{ shippingMethod.id }}" [checked]="idx === 0">
      <i class="checkbox"></i>
      <span>{{ shippingMethod.label }}</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: now what is your result

Comment: The template displays the right value. But FormControl has value null

Comment: can you share your shippingMethods data model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real answer is : **don't do that**

The template is here to tell how you display your data and bind users actions to your component logic, not to perform logic by itself. Its hard to test, hard to maintain and ugly.

You should do that in the component by listening to your observable like :

```
// after initialisation of your observable
shippingMethods$.tap(methods => {
    // we use tap to not make a double subscription
    // group is your FormGroup
    if (!this.group.get('shipping_method').value) {
        this.group.get('shipping_method').setValue(methods[0].id);
    }
});
```

But, if you really want your can perform such assignation logic inside the template like this :

```
{{ myvar = value }}
```

It will display nothing but make the assignation. For your case i made a stackblitz that you can find [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-opxnew)

I added a FormGroup in the example to make it work and remove the Observable logic to make it easier to implement :

The main "template logic" *( man it hurts! )* is that inside the `ngFor` :

```
<span *ngIf="idx === 0 && !group.get('shipping_method').value">
    {{ group.get('shipping_method').setValue(shippingMethod.id)}}
</span>
```

it make the assignation only for the first item if no value is already set in the `FormGroup`

But again place this logic inside the component.